# How to fix memory not being released onfinish?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, memory-leaks

I have a 3 activity application, having multi image and data in them, the problem is that for each time I start Activity 2 and finish it, calling it again will allocate memory without releasing old memory on finish, so while activity 2 needs 22MB of memory, getting back and calling it again for 10 times will allocate 220MB.

Any suggestions? Or am I doing something wrong?

Edit:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,OptionSelecterDialog.OnSelectingResult {

private boolean mShowingBack = false;
Runnable runnable;
Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.ad, new CardFlipActivity.CardFrontFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    findViewById(R.id.daily_deals).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.companies).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.manage_products).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = null;//=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,TodayDeals.class);
     switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.daily_deals:
            intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, TodayDeals.class);
            break;
        case R.id.companies:
            intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Categories.class);
            break;
        case R.id.manage_products:
            OptionSelecterDialog dialog = new OptionSelecterDialog();
            String[] array = {"Deals","Products"};
            dialog.setOptions(array);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            dialog.show(ft, null);
            break;
    }
    if (intent != null) {

        Main2Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                flipCard();

            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }catch (Exception E){}
        }
    };
    runnable.run();
    super.onResume();
}

private void flipCard() {
    if (mShowingBack) {

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(
                    R.animator.flip_in_left,
                    R.animator.flip_out_left,
                    R.animator.flip_in_left,
                    R.animator.flip_out_left).replace(R.id.ad, new CardFlipActivity.CardFrontFragment()).commit();
            mShowingBack = false;

        return;

    }

    mShowingBack = true;


    try {
        Fragment fragment = new CardFlipActivity.CardBackFragment();
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()

                .setCustomAnimations(
                        R.animator.flip_in_left,
                        R.animator.flip_out_left,
                        R.animator.flip_in_left,
                        R.animator.flip_out_left)

                .replace(R.id.ad, fragment)

                .commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onSelectingResult(int result) {
    Intent intent = null;
    switch(result){
        case 0 :break;

        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, ManageProducts.class);
            break;
    }

    if(intent!=null) {
        Main2Activity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and having the same issue on activity 3:

```
public class TodayDeals extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_today_deals);
    findViewById(R.id.samsung).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(TodayDeals.this,TodayDeal.class);
                    TodayDeals.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );

    findViewById(R.id.back).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: if your images are bitmaps try to use Bitmap.recycle() in onDestroy().

Comment: @Teddy activity 3 only contain a listview even though I am still facing same issue.

Comment: You don't seem to "finish()" Main2Activity anywhere, just to start new activities. If you get "back" from the new activities by using "startActivity()", there may indeed be several instances of Main2Activity in the application stack. The same may be true for activity 3 if the user repeatedly clicks the "R.id.samsung" button.

Comment: @0X0nosugar in activity 2 I use back button to finish it by default, so basically i have to go back to the old instance of Main2Activity?

Comment: Maybe we have a misunderstanding here: is acitivity 2 the same as Main2Activity?

Comment: @0X0nosugar yeah, and to point that I tracked its life cycle it's passing through pause>stop>destroy but i don't understand why it still holds the memory it allocated for this activity.

Comment: Well, the code you posted so far should be no problem: you remove the Handler callback and even if the R.id.ad fragments contained a reference to the activity, the fragments will be destroyed together with the activity (or earlier by replacing them). Now you were talking of many images/ data. This usually means starting an AsyncTask or some other thread (of which your code does not show anything) either from the activity or from one of the fragments. If a separate thread has a reference to something with a Context *and* it's still alive "onDestroy()" then that is most likely your memory leak.